# How to coordinate image and matrix input in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I want to create a model in Keras that receives images from a directory with `n` images and a matrix input with shape of `n rows X m features`.

I know how to create a generator from a directory and also how to input the matrix data into the model, but i would like to use different networks and then `merge` them.

How can I make sure that the `n-th image` and the `n-th row` are fed at the same step? And when using batches these coordinate as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They **are** fed as the same sample, don't worry. Keras will demand you to have `n` in the first dimension for both input tensors, so, there is nothing that can go wrong. Make sure that `images.shape[0] == matrix.shape[0]`. That is the only condition and it will grant parallel samples from both inputs.

```
imageInput = Input((side1,side2,channels))   
matrixInput = Input((m,))

#use these two inputs in a model here
.....
#merge the two sides somehow

outputTensorFromTheLastLayer = #get this from your last layer in the model

#instantiate the model with 2 inputs
model = Model([imageInput,matrixInput], outputTensorFromTheLastLayer)
```

As for merging there are lots of possibilities, and you have to be creative.

Pay attention to the shapes of the tensors you're trying to merge and use some of the possible merge layers: https://keras.io/layers/merge/